# dereferencing and assignment of a pointer resulting in wrong value C++

Tags: c++

For the context I was trying to make a matrix class where you can create matrix objects and do operations with them in C++. At the moment I am having an issue with dereferencing a pointer and assigning it values.

my function that is assigning values is this  :

```
static float* assign_elements(float ary[], int row, int col){


    float* mat;
        for( int i=0 ; i< row * col ;i ++){

            float* loc = mat +i;
            *loc= ary[i];


        }
    return mat;
}
```

The parameter values I passed on are:

```
float ary[]={2.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
int row =2; int col=2;
```

What my console output was after I print it out using `cout<<*mat<<","<<*(mat +1)<<","<<*(mat+2)<<","<<*(mat+3)<<"\n";`
:

```
1,0,0,1
```

Comment: `mat` is uninitialized.

Comment: `static float*` ?  Everything that follows is very very fragile ...

Comment: Hi thank you!, I missed it somehow!!!.

Comment: @AmalDevHari You might miss seeing that a variable is uninitialized, but your compiler won't. Enable your compiler's warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) so it can help you catch errors.